# Custom Gradle plugin to resolve Ivy dependencies

Tags: gradle, ivy

I am writing a gradle plugin that extends the URLResolver and I am hitting a problem.

We have a project that bundles a number of libraries together, the bundle specifies the versions of the constituent libraries in a mapping file and in the dependencies file we specify a version of 'default' unless we want to use a specific library version.

At the moment this is all defined in the build.gradle file until such time as I can refactor into a stand-alone plugin.

My plugin code looks like this:

```
class DefaultURLResolverPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    void apply(Project project) {
        project.convention.plugins.DefaultURLResolverPluginConvention = new DefaultURLResolverPluginConvention(project.ver.MsParts)
    }
}

class DefaultURLResolverPluginConvention {
    private final String partsVersion;

    public DefaultURLResolverPluginConvention(String partsVersion) {
        this.partsVersion = partsVersion
    }

    public DefaultURLResolver newDefaultURLResolver() {
        return new DefaultURLResolver(partsVersion)
    }
}

import java.text.ParseException

class DefaultURLResolver extends org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.URLResolver {

    Map versionMapping = new HashMap()

    public DefaultURLResolver(String partsVersion) {
        File defaulstFile = new File("/parts/" + partsVersion + "/etc/bundles/library-versions.default.properties")
        for (String line : defaulstFile.readLines()) {
            if (line.length() > 0 && !line.startsWith('#')) {
                String[] mapping = line.split('=')
                versionMapping.put(mapping[0], mapping[1])
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolvedModuleRevision getDependency(org.apache.ivy.core.module.descriptor.DependencyDescriptor dd, org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveData data)
    throws ParseException
    {
        org.apache.ivy.core.module.descriptor.DependencyDescriptor lookup = dd
        if ("default".equals(dd.getDependencyRevisionId().getRevision())) {
            org.apache.ivy.core.module.id.ModuleRevisionId moduleRevisionId = dd.getDependencyRevisionId()
            String key = moduleRevisionId.getOrganisation() + "." + moduleRevisionId.getName() + ".version.default"
            println "looking for key " + key + " found: " + versionMapping.get(key)
            org.apache.ivy.core.module.id.ModuleRevisionId defaultedRevisionId = org.apache.ivy.core.module.id.ModuleRevisionId.intern(new org.apache.ivy.core.module.id.ModuleRevisionId(
                org.apache.ivy.core.module.id.ModuleId.newInstance(moduleRevisionId.getOrganisation(), moduleRevisionId.getName()), versionMapping.get(key)))
            lookup = dd.clone(defaultedRevisionId)
        }
        return super.getDependency(lookup, data);
    }
}
```

The dependency resolution works fine to find the correct ivy.xml file but then I get a NullPointerException, presumably when it is trying to find the actual jar. What I am looking for is some pointers on resources that will tell me how to fix it, obviously if someone can tell me the solution that would be great. :-)

The stacktrace I am getting is:

```
org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolveException: Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':commonxsds:compile'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver.wrapException(ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:51           )
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver.access$000(ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:29)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver$BrokenResolvedConfiguration.rethrowFailure(ErrorHandlingArtif           actDependencyResolver.java:131)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:461)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:202)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration_Decorated.getFiles(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext$FileTreeConverter.convertInto(DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.jav           a:191)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.doResolve(DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.java:103)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.resolveAsFileTrees(DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext$FileTreeConverter.convertInto(DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.jav           a:182)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.doResolve(DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.java:98)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.resolveAsFileTrees(DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection$1.resolve(CompositeFileCollection.java:88)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.getSourceCollections(CompositeFileCollection.java:143)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileTree.getSourceCollections(CompositeFileTree.java:30)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.getFiles(CompositeFileCollection.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.iterator(AbstractFileCollection.java:60)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultFileSnapshotter.snapshot(DefaultFileSnapshotter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.rules.InputFilesStateChangeRule.create(InputFilesStateChangeRule.java:33)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.rules.TaskUpToDateState.<init>(TaskUpToDateState.java:48)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.changes.DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository$TaskArtifactStateImpl.getStates(DefaultTaskArtifactStateReposit           ory.java:151)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.changes.DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository$TaskArtifactStateImpl.isUpToDate(DefaultTaskArtifactStateReposi           tory.java:72)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:45)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ContextualisingTaskExecuter.execute(ContextualisingTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheLockAcquiringTaskExecuter$1.run(CacheLockAcquiringTaskExecuter.java:39)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:124)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:112)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.useCache(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:134)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheLockAcquiringTaskExecuter.execute(CacheLockAcquiringTaskExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:282)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.executeTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:48)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:27)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:89)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:67)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter$1.run(TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:124)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:112)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.useCache(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:134)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter.execute(TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter.java:29)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:67)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:166)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:113)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:81)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:42)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartStopIfBuildAndStop.execute(StartStopIfBuildAndStop.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ReturnResult.execute(ReturnResult.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:70)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:68)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:68)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:59)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator.runCommand(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:186)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.doBuild(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:49)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.HandleStop.execute(HandleStop.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.CatchAndForwardDaemonFailure.execute(CatchAndForwardDaemonFailure.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DefaultDaemonCommandExecuter.executeCommand(DefaultDaemonCommandExecuter.java:48)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler$ConnectionWorker.handleCommand(DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler.java:155)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler$ConnectionWorker.receiveAndHandleCommand(DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler.java:           128)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler$ConnectionWorker.run(DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler.java:116)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:66)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.result.ResolutionResultBuilder.resolvedConfiguration(ResolutionResultBuilder.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DependencyGraphBuilder.assembleResult(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:164)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DependencyGraphBuilder.resolve(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DefaultDependencyResolver.resolve(DefaultDependencyResolver.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver$1.create(CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver$1.create(CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:37)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:124)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.useCache(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:130)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultCacheLockingManager.useCache(DefaultCacheLockingManager.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver.resolve(CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:37)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.SelfResolvingDependencyResolver.resolve(SelfResolvingDependencyResolver.java:41)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ShortcircuitEmptyConfigsArtifactDependencyResolver.resolve(ShortcircuitEmptyConfigsArtifactDependency           Resolver.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver.resolve(ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultConfigurationResolver.resolve(DefaultConfigurationResolver.java:42)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolveNow(DefaultConfiguration.java:240)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.getResolvedConfiguration(DefaultConfiguration.java:230)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration_Decorated.getResolvedConfiguration(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:459)
    ... 97 more
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like I am missing a factory class definition, which is why the resolution is failing.

Comment: There was more to this problem than a missing factory class, I needed to manipulate the descriptor version ids as well as the ResolvedModuleRevision ids.